# How can i handle "refresh" event on my page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, web, html

I want to display a confirmation popup "Do you want to refresh this page" once user clicks "refresh". If user selects yes in popup, then page should refresh otherwise it should stay as is.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use this javascript code to check page refresh.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
return "Do you want to refresh this page";
};
```

Comment: Really helpful answer vinit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it worked

```
  window.onbeforeunload = 
     function(){
       return "Refreshing page will result in loss of data, do you want to continue ?";
     };
```